# ScrollPane in JavaFx does not update inside pane contents when user scroll window

Tags: user-interface, javafx, updating, scenebuilder, scrollpane

I would like to share what I have recently discover (problem + solution). After doing changes via SceneBuilder in some properties of a ScrollPane component (this pane is the parent-pane in my GUI), my Java application stopped updating the contents of the GUI pane when the user uses the scroll bars. The program was fine before, so I have decided to undo all those property changes in the ScrollPane object and redo one by one again and testing when that undesirable problem would come back again.

In my case, the property that caused the ScrollPane "bad behave" was the "layout >> padding". If I set the values (left, right, up, and down) to any number but zero I got the undesirable behavior. Setting them to zero the behavior went away.

This problem might have been solved in recent JavaFx updates, but in the company that I work for, I don't have the permissions to install new updates, only the TI group, what can take months. So if you are in the same situation as myself, the hint given above might help you too.

I just want to share this with the group.

Thanks